# Check array containing array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I searched this question but the answer are redundant so I would like to ask, without any matching, how to check any array containing another array or not.

I expect this `['abc']` to be false because it doesn't have another array within it, and this is true `['abc',[1]]`. Many example do a complex loop to find the array value, but what's the most simple way to know whether within an array there's an array exist?

Comment: Iterate, then check with `Array.isArray`.

Comment: Arrays have no magic powers to know what they contain (no indexes or stored knowledge of what's in them).  You will just have to iterate the items in the array and check to see if any slots in the array contain an array.

Comment: @elclanrs why this doesn't work? `$.each(arr,function(){
            console.log(this.isArray); // undefined 
        });`

Comment: @tonyyew `var arr = [1, 3, [5, 7]];

$.each(arr, function () {
    console.log(Array.isArray(this));
});`

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.some` , `Array.isArray`

```js
var arr1 = ["abc"];

var arr2 = ["abc", [1]];

var res1 = arr1.some(function(item) {
  return Array.isArray(item);
});

var res2 = arr2.some(function(item) {
  return Array.isArray(item);
});

document.body.innerHTML = "arr1 contains `Array`:" + res1
                            + "<br> arr2 contains `Array`:" + res2;
```

---

> `$.each(arrayTag,function(){ console.log(this.isArray); });` why this
>   doesn't work?

Note, jQuery not appear necessary to return expected results.

Try adding parameters to `$.each()` callback `function(key, item)` calling `Array.isArray(item)` on element within callback

```js
var arr1 = ["abc"];

var arr2 = ["abc", [1]];

$.each(arr1, function(key, item) {
  console.log(Array.isArray(item))
});

$.each(arr2, function(key, item) {
  console.log(Array.isArray(item))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$.each(arrayTag,function(){
            console.log(this.isArray);
        });` why this doesn't work?

Comment: Why not just use `return Array.isArray(item)`?

Comment: @tonyyew Change `this.isArray` to `Array.isArray(this);`

Comment: @tonyyew _"$.each(arrayTag,function(){ console.log(this.isArray); }); why this doesn't work?"_ Try defining parameters at `$.each(arrayTag,function(key, item) { console.log(Array.isArray(item)); });` See updated post

Comment: It's just bizarre to do a string match on a constructor and to ever even offer that as an option when `Array.isArray()` is built into the language to do just that.  FYI, your constructor string match could easily generate false positives too.

Comment: @jfriend00 _"FYI, your constructor string match could easily generate false positives too."_ Can create example to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 - Example that shows false positive: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/eb7wz33e/

Comment: @jfriend00 Good example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery `filter()` method to return only array elements of the array; and to check if an element is an array you can use the jQuery `type()` method. If the number return is greater than `0` then the array contains an array -- `true`; otherwise, `false`.

```js
function hasArray( array ) {
    return $.grep( array, function(v,i) {
        return $.type( v ) == 'array';
    }).length > 0;
}

console.log( hasArray( [ 'abc', [ 1 ] ] ) ); //true
console.log( hasArray( [ 'abc' ] ) );       //false
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to actually grab the inner array:

```
var array = ['a', [1,2,3]]

array.filter(function(element){
    return Array.isArray(element)
})
```

but if you just want a boolean

```
var isAnArray = false
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++ ) {
    if(Array.isArray(array[i])) {
        isAnArray = true
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: does break the same with return false?

Comment: No. break is simply going to stop the loop once you meet the condition. return will also stop the loop, but also stop execution of everything after the loop.